# iscsi not working after host reboot

Tags: iscsi, openstack, centos7, cinder

I have a host that is acting as both an iscsi initiator and target. It's an OpenStack box that acts as both the storage node (cinder) and also as a compute node. There is also another compute nodes on the network that just acts as initiator to this target.

The target is a Centos 7 box with an ip address of 192.168.1.10.

Once I create a virtual machine, I can see the volume and 'targetcli ls' shows the LUN and the ACL.

I've copied a number of log outputs to pastebin. These include

- targetcli ls
- systemctl status iscsi
- systemctl status iscsid

I captured logs at the following points:

- Before virt creation - http://pastebin.com/vpjKM256
- After virt creation (all working) - http://pastebin.com/LB5bhYDR
- After reboot (not working) - http://pastebin.com/V23BSYY3
- After creating a new virt (working for new volume only) post reboot - http://pastebin.com/Jpq9AijN

After a reboot, 'targetcli ls' only shows the LUN but not the ACL. I also have errors in the iscsi and iscsid status information.

**iscsid errors**

> Jan 04 16:03:58 myserver.mydomain iscsid[1398]: connect to 192.168.1.10:3260 failed (Connection refused)
>   Jan 04 16:04:25 myserver.mydomain iscsid[1398]: conn 0 login rejected: initiator failed authorization with target
>   Jan 04 16:04:25 myserver.mydomain iscsid[1398]: Connection1:0 to [target: iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-e764f202-b414-424f-b02a-595f797b6b9c, portal: 192.168.1.10,3260] through [iface: default] is shutdown.

**iscsi errors**

> Jan 04 16:03:36 myserver.mydomain iscsi-mark-root-nodes[1042]: iscsiadm: No active sessions.
>   Jan 04 16:04:25 myserver.mydomain iscsiadm[1172]: iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-e764f202-b414-424f-b02a-595f797b6b9c, portal: 192.168.1.10,3260].
>   Jan 04 16:04:25 myserver.mydomain iscsiadm[1172]: iscsiadm: initiator reported error (24 - iSCSI login failed due to authorization failure)
>   Jan 04 16:04:25 myserver.mydomain iscsiadm[1172]: iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals
>   Jan 04 16:04:25 myserver.mydomain iscsiadm[1172]: Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-e764f202-b414-424f-b02a-595f797b6b9c, portal: 192.168.1.10,3260] (multiple)

If I then create a new virt (which creates a new volume), iscsi works for that volume. There is still no ACL associated with the one created pre-reboot.

Rebooting causes the new one to fail too.

My initiatorname in /etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi is 'iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:4fc3b5297ef1', so I tried doing the following, and rebooting, with no improvement

> cd /iscsi/iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-e764f202-b414-424f-b02a-595f797b6b9c/tpg1/acls
>   create iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:4fc3b5297ef1

This produced the following output:

> Created Node ACL for iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:4fc3b5297ef1
>   Created mapped LUN 0.